# Data comes repeaitively from databse to JSP on refreshing the page with RequestMethod.GET

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to pass data from DAO to JSP using ModelMap. It works but, when I refresh that page, same data comes repeatedly on every refresh. I want data not to come again and again on refreshing the page. Help me for this issue.

```
    @Autowired
    private SelectInfo selectInfo; /* Instance of SelectInfo DAO class injected here, here the method of fetching data from databse is defined and fetched data is passed to GetInfo bean*/

    @Autowired
    private GetDetail getDetails; /* GetDetail is the bean where the values are stored which are coming from database */

    @RequestMapping(value="/selectInfo", method=RequestMethod.GET)

    public String registerComplete(ModelMap model,HttpSession session,HttpServletResponse res) {

    if(session.getAttribute("user")==null) {
           return "redirect:/";
    }else {     

    selectInfo.getInfo(); /*getInfo is the method defined in SelectInfo class which fetch data from database*/

    /* the values are adding in modelmap using getter method from GetInfo bean */
    model.put("cities", getDetails.getCities());
    model.put("theaters", getDetails.getTheaters());
    model.put("movies", getDetails.getMovies());
    model.put("dates", getDetails.getDates());
    model.put("timings", getDetails.getTimings());

    return "cities";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So you do not want call your db each time when page refreshes? I think you can try caching in that case. Please take a look at example here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/

You can just add annotation on your controller method.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/selectInfo", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@Cacheable
public String registerComplete(ModelMap model,HttpSession session,HttpServletResponse res) {
    //your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing the data using modelMap means, data will be transferred each time a page load or refreshed. In order to load the data once use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Create new method in controller class to return data like this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/cities", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Object registerComplete(){
  return getDetails.getCities()
}
```

In javascript check the sessionStorage if its null then load the data using ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if(sessionStorage.cities ==null){

        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : "/cities",
            contentType:'application/json',
            data:JSON.stringify(data),
            success : function(response) {
                sessionStorage.cities =response;
            }
        });

    }

}) ;
```

By this you can restrict data load on each refresh

Answer (score 0):

Caching is the natural way to avoid unnecessary trips to database. Spring provides support for this using `@Cacheable` annotation.

If you are using Spring Boot, things are easier for you. Ensure that you have got `spring-boot-starter-cache` in your dependencies or one of your spring starters depends on `spring-boot-starter-cache`. Then you can annotate your DAO method like so:

```java
@Component
public class SelectInfo {
  ...
  @Cacheable("dbInfo")
  public <returnType> getInfo() {
    // Implementation of the method
  }
  ...
}
```

Putting the `Cacheable` annotation over the method in your DAO is advised since it is responsible for fetching the actual data that you want to cache.

If you are not using Spring Boot, you'll have to include a Cache Provider and configure a bean for that provider. The details of how to do this can be found in the Spring Caching Docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html#boot-features-caching-provider